# Externalize the Configuration (appSettings.json) file in ASp.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I have developed a default Web API project using .Net Core Web API template. I would like to externalize the appSettings.json file to some other location instead of the default root location.
Below is the piece of code that I'm using.

[image]

I'm not able to read the settings from the Config file. Is there  a way to retrieve them?

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: What do you mean by *not able to read*? Was there any error? Or the key values did not appear in `IConfiguration`?

Comment: Why do you want to read json file outside the default publish folder, that will not include in source control which i think appesttings.json should be .